# Add script to footer - on post editor

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, metabox, footer

How do you add a script on the footer of the post editor ? 
I'm adding a meta box under the post editor and I need to include a javascript before the closing body tag (on the footer)

How do I achieve this ?

The script is not needed on the front-end just on that meta_box (just on the post editor page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hook into `'admin_footer-post-new.php'` and `'admin_footer-post.php'`, check the global variable `$post_type`:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'wpse_73692_script' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'wpse_73692_script' );

function wpse_73692_script()
{
    if ( 'post' !== $GLOBALS['post_type'] )
        return;

    ?>
<script>alert( '<?php echo $GLOBALS['post_type'];?>' );</script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Where would you add this on a multi-site installation where you just want the script to fire in just one particular site?

Comment: @Lynn In a plugin. Themes should handle the front-end only.

Comment: Ugh.  For reasons i can't go into nor care to debate, I can't do this via a plugin.  Or install a new one (new company policy right now).  And out of interest in learning WP, I want to know if I could just put this into the functions.php file relevant to the one site I want my jQuery to fire on (when the Publish button is clicked) and have it hook into admin footer from there.

Comment: @Lynn Then do it so. Try it, it should work.